# iText 7 pdfHTML setCharset doesn't work on MS Server 2016

Tags: encoding, itext7, pdfhtml

I just finished a new service for creating pdf export which contains parts with html strings (two cells in a table), so I had to use pdfHTML. My code part:

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setCharset("UTF-8");
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
InputStream isStav = new ByteArrayInputStream((pdfData.get().getStav() == null ? "" : pdfData.get().getStav()).getBytes());
List<IElement> elements =
HtmlConverter.convertToElements(isStav, properties);
```

Everything worked perfectly on my local machine, but the setCharset("UTF-8") part gets ignored, when I deploy my project to a Wildfly server (hosted on microsoft windows server 2016).
the result when I download a pdf looks like this:
"Nemali by však zásadne preká�a? v testovaní.".

How can I set the charSet correctly on the server? Is it servers fault, or should I change something in my code?
As a default font I use PdfFont, but I could't pass it to FontProvider:

```
PdfFont fNormal = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA, "CP1250");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the missing character is in CP1250?

Comment: Of course, cp1250 contains all slovak and czech characters like 'č' or 'ž'. Encoding works perfectly for other elements (where I defined the PdfFont), but unfortunately I cannot set it for HtmlConverter, and I don't want it, because the data are from tinyMCE editor (angular). The thing is, on my local computer (embedded tomcat on port 8080), works like a charm, but when I deploy the war output of my project to a wildfly server on MS windows server 2016, the encoding of HtmlConverter gets somehow ignored.